# Agregar un input text con un radio button

Tags: javascript, html

Ya modifiqué lo que un usuario me comentó sobre que puse un input fuera del label, así como también no hay ninguna regla en mi css que oculte el input de texto. El código que agregaré no tiene ni css, y por alguna razón sigue sin funcionarme, igual alguien me había dicho acerca de que tenía dos "OnClick" en un mismo input, pero eso ya no lo entendí :c
Ya me di cuenta de que cuando le quito la etiqueta Form, mi código ya funciona, pero al hacer eso, ¿ya no voy a poder enviar la información de mi formulario, verdad?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registro de Cédula</title>


</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>CÉDULA ÚNICA DE REGISTRO DEL ALUMNO.</h1></center>
    <center><h4>NOTA: Este documento es estrictamente confidencial.</h4></center>
    <main>
        <form action="" class="formulario" id="formulario">
            
                    <!-- Grupo: Medicamentos -->
            <div class="formulario__grupo-input" id="grupo__correo">
        <center><label  class="formulario__label">¿Tomas algún medicamento?</label></center>
            <div class="input-group" id="RadioOptionCSS">
                <span class="radio">

                    <label>Si<input type="radio" name="option" onclick="option(1)"/></label>

                    <label>No<input type="radio" name="option" onclick="option(0)"/></label>
                    <label id="deliveryDate" class="formulario__label">¿Cuáles?<input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="datosMedicamentos" id="deliveryDate"></label>
                </span>
            </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">Seleccione una de las dos opciones diponibles.</p>
    </div>

        </form>
    </main>
    <script>
            function option(x){
    if(x===0){
        document.getElementById('deliveryDate').style.visibility='hidden';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('deliveryDate').style.visibility='visible';
    }
    return;
}
option(0);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Al copiar y pegar tu código, muestra el input cuando se selecciona "Sí" y lo oculta cuando se selecciona "No" ¿Qué es lo que no sirve?

Comment: Como dicen, tu código tal cual funciona. Te recomiendo mirar que: 1. El código JavaScript está siendo descargado e incluido en tu web. 2. No hay ninguna regla CSS que mantiene el `input` invisible (Ej: `#deliveryDate { display: none; }`)

Comment: Si tu codigo funciona probandolo solo, pero en tu proyecto no funciona es porque seguramente algo esta sobrescribiendo ese codigo, eso puede pasar en javascript el concepto se llama shadowing y en css Specificity, para probar que es esto el problema cambiale el nombre a tus ids, funciones y al name, poneles algo nose como unos numeros al final si funciona con eso es porque en alguna otra parte del js o css se esta haciendo algo con esos identificadores

Comment: A ver, no se porque no te funciona, pero hay errores de HTML básicos. 1) Dejas puesto un **class** sin más en el input del **no**, 2) Dejas estos dos atributos pegados en el mismo input: `onclick="option(0)"checked`, 3) Cierras un input con `</input>` en el que tiene el name **datosMedicamentos**, y además fuera del `<label>` (los inputs o se autocierran o se dejan tal cual sin cerrar) 4) Usas `<label>` para todo, incluso para el título que no se necesita 5) No usas el atributo **for=** en los label, el cual ayuda a seleccionar la opción pulsando sobre el texto y no el radio... arregla eso 1ro

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero si tienes un `<form>` necesitas tener un input type submit, creo....

Comment: Has probado en una ventana de incógnito (Si usas Chrome) o  Ventana privada (Firefox) ? A veces cuando trabajas con scripts, estos se quedan cargados y pareciera que no se reflejan los cambios

Comment: El input de type submit, si lo tengo, lo que subí solo es una parte del código, lo único que falto fue subir lo del submit, pero mi problema es que cuando tiene la etiqueta form, mi script

Answer (score 0):

No hay un código JavaScript completo en el enunciado de la pregunta pero probando con esto a mi me ha funcionado:

```html
    <div class="formulario__grupo-input" id="grupo__correo">
        <center><label  class="formulario__label">¿Tomas algún medicamento?</label></center>
            <div class="input-group" id="RadioOptionCSS">
                <span class="radio">

                    <label>Si<input type="radio" name="option" onclick="option(1)"/></label>

                    <label>No<input type="radio" class name="option" onclick="option(0)"checked/></label>
                    <label id="deliveryDate" class="formulario__label">¿Cuáles?<input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="datosMedicamentos" id="deliveryDate"></label></input>
                </span>
            </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">Seleccione una de las dos opciones diponibles.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function option (x) {
            if(x===0){
                document.getElementById('deliveryDate').style.visibility='hidden';
            }else{
                document.getElementById('deliveryDate').style.visibility='visible';
            }
            return;
        }
        option(0);
    </script>
```

Comment: Buen día, esto no es una respuesta, debería ser un comentario. Saludos

Comment: Por que exactamente? le he propuesto la forma en la que a mi me funciona para que lo pruebe

Comment: No se que sea lo que sucede, pero al menos en mi caso el código no funciona, no se si este llamando mal al archivo js, o por algún otro factor

Comment: Añade en la pregunta como llamas al archivo y si en consola te aparece algún error para que podamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: @DavidFernándezFlores Creo que se refiere a que tan solo lo has puesto en un snippet, sin más cambios, o si los hay, no los has documentado. Durante las revisiones, a veces cambiamos las preguntas y los ponemos nosotros mismos si vemos que se pueden ejecutar, por lo tanto no es una respuesta en sí, es solo otra forma de verlo. En este caso iba a hacerlo yo pero he visto demasiados fallos básicos de HTML para que valga la pena y mejor que los arregle el OP primero antes de ponerlo en un snippet. Si pretendias mostrarle que funcionaba lo podrias poner en un comentario con enlace a un fiddle.net

Comment: @masterguru Tampoco es necesario un enlace a un fiddle. Lo necesario es que explique qué modificaciones ha hecho. Para el autor de la respuesta: recuerda que en [es.so] no basta con "dejar solo el código" y ya: no es un repositorio. Puede que otros usuarios más adelante lleguen a esta respuesta y no comprendan su funcionamiento.